# Распределение сообщений в патрициях кафки

Tags: apache-kafka

Начинаю использовать Кафку в проекте и не могу разобраться в нескольких вопросах. Каждый топик в Кафке разбит на партиции и продюсеры при записи событий с key=null в топик в классическом исполнении используют round robin стратегию, когда сообщения по очереди пишутся в партиции. В консьюмер группе, если количество консьюмеров = количеству партиций в топике, то каждый консьюмер читает из выделенной ему партиции.

1. То есть каждый консьюмер видит не все сообщения в топике, а то только ту часть, которая попала в его партицию?
2. Если нужно, чтобы все консьюмеры видели все сообщения в топике, то они не должны быть в одной группе?
3. Если в один топик пишутся события для разных консьюмеров и они находят нужное им событие по определенному uuid и консьюмеры не объединены в группу, то получается каждый прочтет свое сообщение и тк его прочтут не все консьюмеры, то оно будет лежать в топике, пока не выйдет его время жизни и Кафка сама его не почистит?

Comment: ох. тут нужно долго отвечать. и вопрос будет зависит от настройки консюмера и продюсера

Answer (score 0):

**1**
Да, это так. Каждый консьюмер в консьюмер-группе читает только из своей выделенной партиции топика. Если количество консьюмеров совпадает с количеством партиций в топике, то каждый консьюмер будет читать только из своей партиции, и соответственно не будет видеть сообщения, которые находятся в других партициях. Это может быть полезно для обработки большого объема данных и для масштабирования консьюмеров.

Однако, если количество консьюмеров не совпадает с количеством партиций, то некоторые партиции будут обрабатываться несколькими консьюмерами. Это может быть полезно, если некоторые из партиций генерируют больше данных, чем другие.

Используя партиционность, можно обеспечить балансировку нагрузки между консьюмерами и обеспечить распределенную обработку данных. Это может улучшить производительность и масштабируемость вашей системы.

**2** Нет. Если мы добавим ещё одного консьюмера в группу, то партиции автоматически распределятся между ними. Скажем, у нас 3 партиции. c1(consumer1) теперь будет читать сообщения из первой и второй партиции, а c2 — из третьей. Добавив ещё одного консьюмера (c3), мы добьёмся идеального распределения нагрузки, и каждый из консьюмеров в этой группе будет читать данные из одной партиции.
А вот если мы добавим в группу ещё одного консьюмера (c4), то он не будет задействован в обработке сообщений вообще.

Важно понять: внутри одной консьюмер-группы партиции назначаются консьюмерам уникально, чтобы избежать повторной обработки.

Если консьюмеры не справляются с текущим объёмом данных, то следует добавить новую партицию в топик. Только после этого консьюмер c4 начнёт свою работу.

**3** Я не понял. Если 1 партиция, где лежат разного рода данные, тогда создайте разные консюмер-группы под каждый случай, либо делайте разные топики для каждого типа сообщения.
Да, кафка удалит сообщение после retention периода